# Pressure tank losing pressure

Tags: water-pressure

My pressure tank is losing pressure. It cycles about once every hour if no water is used. It turns on at 30# and goes off at 50#.

The tank is less than a year old and looks in good condition. I just started to notice a few weeks ago, but recently more often. Not sure if it's getting worse or I'm just noticing it more since I'm now aware of it.

Here is what I've done so far:

First, I checked for leaks and cannot find any. There is some discolored dirt under the house that looks like it could be wet, but according to a plumber I spoke to, if I was losing 20# of pressure an hour, it would be around 5 gallons of water and easy to spot. I'm not sure if that calculation is correct, but I definitely would spot a leak if that much water was leaking out, even if I couldn't see exactly where a leak would be.

Next I closed the shutoff valve just after the tank/pressure valve/pressure switch and the pressure didn't drop at all. The plumber told me that since the pressure did not drop, the leak was not from the tank the the well and that it had to be someplace in the house. Again, I could not find any leaks.

Next I checked the air pressure in the tank, which should have been 28#, but it was at 36#. I adjusted the pressure accordingly and will see what happens from here. I was thinking that maybe with too much pressure it could cause water to leak slowly out of joints, which may be the discoloration I seen at certain spots under the house, although there is quite a bit of condensation.

Anyone know what else I can check? I have to be losing water someplace, unless there is a problem elsewhere, such as with the tank, etc., but I would think that with the shutoff valve off, if I had a tank problem, I still would have lost pressure.

Thanks ahead for any suggestions ...

Comment: I would double check for leaks again. Make sure you actually cover everything. Toilets, sinks, water softener, maybe a sump pump, etc.

Comment: Did you check the pressure in the tank while the system was pressurized?  Pressure must be taken off the system before checking tank pressure.  Nevertheless I do believe the leak is past the tank, by your description.

Comment: Yes, I first shut off the electric to the pump then drained the water from inside the house until it stopped and the pressure gauge dropped to zero. That is when I checked the pressure in the tank and it was too high. I then corrected the pressure to 2# below cut in pressure (28# / 30#).

Answer (score 0):

Your tank is not loosing pressure you have a leak, a toilet, or faucet somewhere in the house is the most likely cause. I have seen copper pipe riddled with tiny pin holes That were so small it raised the humidity several months later ew found the first ones. In that home we had to replace most of the copper it may have been due to cheap pipe or high mineral content not sure as the house was all copper (no galvanized pipe issues) or dielectric unions needed.

Answer (score 0):

This certainly sounds like a leak, particularly the "shut valve and problem stops" part.

If you don't have a puddle, it's probably leaking into a drain.

Toilets and water softeners top my list for common "leak to drain unnoticed" items. If your valving permits, start isolating parts of the system or individual fixtures. One (or more, but probably one) of them is leaking.

Correcting the air pressure in the tank is good, but has nothing to do with your leaky problem. I trust you did that with the water side drained/at 0 PSI?

Comment: Yes, the water side was drained to 0 PSI.